# Search on two column when search text is separated by space

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
------------------------
id | first_name | last_name
1. | John       | Doe
2. | David      | Blain
```

To search for a row against passed search text I am using `iLik` query.

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.first_name ILIKE %John% or t.last_name ILIKE %John%;`

Above works.

But I want to search for full name, both on first_name and last_name. It does not return the row.

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.first_name ILIKE %John Doe% or t.last_name ILIKE %John Doe%;`

Above empty result.

How can I make this to search on both the columns matching against sub parts of the search text?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE 'John Doe' ILIKE concat('%',t.first_name,'%') or 'John Doe' ILIKE concat('%',t.last_name,'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the columns before searching:

```
WHERE concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) ILIKE '%John Doe%'
```